# Group values from one numpy array based on values from another

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have had a look through SO to see if I can find the answer to my query but I think my knowledge of numpy at this point is too low to know if I have found it or not!

Given two array of the same shape, I would like to group values from array B based on shared values in group A.

For example

```
arraya = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
arrayb = [45,56,75,34,657,67,88,32,56,3,45,8]
```

I essentially want out of this three arrays - 1, 2 and 3 based on the unique values from arraya - they would then contain the values in the same position.

```
array1 = [45,56,75,34]
array2 = [657,67,88,32]
array3 = [56,3,45,8]
```

Any pointers would be great! Thank you SO community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is np.unique() and np.split

```
import numpy as np

arraya = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
arrayb = [45,56,75,34,657,67,88,32,56,3,45,8]

values, indices, counts = np.unique(arraya, return_counts=True, return_index=True)
subarrays=np.split(arrayb,indices)

array1 = subarrays[1]
array2 = subarrays[2]
array3 = subarrays[3]
```

If you don't need separate variables, you can skip the last three lines and just keep them as subarrays and refer to them by index.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am getting somewhere. I cannot work out why I get 11 values, but 12 indices. Any ideas?

Comment: As this confused me for a moment: This will not work when your arraya is not sorted

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

```
np.split(arrayb, np.unique(arraya, return_index=True)[1][1:])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[array([45, 56, 75, 34]), array([657,  67,  88,  32]), array([56,  3, 45,  8])]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) has an option to return the counts. Using that you can construct an array of indices that can be used in conjunction with [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html?highlight=split#numpy.split):

```
>>> counts = np.unique(arraya, return_counts=True)[1]
>>> cumsum = counts.cumsum()[:-1]

>>> np.split(arrayb, cumsum)
[array([45, 56, 75, 34]), array([657,  67,  88,  32]), array([56,  3, 45,  8])]
```